# How to plot the numbers in each of 10 columns for one row in a line chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

This seems so simple. I can easily do it in Excel but I want to automate the process through R. I have installed ggplot2. Using RStudio I have read in my CSV file.

The resulting data frame has over 200 rows, each a town in New Hampshire. The first column is titled "Town" and each row below that has the text name of the town, (e.g., "Concord" or "Lancaster"). Column 2 contains a number for each town (spending per elementary school pupil) and the title of that column in the CSV file is "01/02 Elem PPE"  - but it shows as "X01.02.Elem.PPE" when using View(). Column 3 has similar numbers for each town and its title in View() is "X02.03.Elem.PPE". Columns 4 through 11 are similar.

I just want to plot a line graph of the numbers in columns 2-11 for one row (one town). It will show how the spending per pupil has changed in that town over time. There must be a simple way to do this, but I can't find it.

Please help. I am a 77 year old with some programming experience 3-5 decades ago but new to R and Rstudio only yesterday.

Comment: Hi @DouglasHall, Welcome to StackOverflow and R!  If you can add a little more data to your question it will help others answer.  Please run the command ```dput(head(df,10))``` (and replace ```df``` with the name of your actual dataframe) and then add the resulting output to your question. Just use the ```edit``` button on the bottom left of your question to add.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'll make some new data that mimics yours.  It should have more or less the same properties.

```
library(glue)
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(4314)
mat <- matrix(rpois(40, 5000), ncol=10)
colnames(mat) <- glue("X{sprintf('%2.0f', 1:10)}.{sprintf('%2.0f', 2:11)}.Elem.PPE", sep="") %>% 
  gsub(". ", ".0", ., fixed=TRUE) %>% 
  gsub("X ", "X0", ., fixed=TRUE)

df <- tibble(town = c("Concord", "Lancaster", "Manchester", "Nashua"))
df <- bind_cols(df, as_tibble(mat))
```

Now, this is where you would start.  I'm going to assume that you read your csv into an object called `df`. The first thing you should do to make plotting easier is to pivot the data from wide-form (one-row and 10 columns per observation) to long-form with 1 column and 10 rows per observation.   I'm going to save this in an object called `df2`.  The `pivot_longer` function is in the `tidyr` package.  The first argument is the columns that you want to change from wide- to long-form, in this case, it's everything *except* `town`.  Then you tell it a variable name for the column names and a variable name for the values.  Then, I'm just using a couple of regular expressions to go from `X01.02.Elem.PPE` to `01/02` for plotting purposes.

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-town, names_to="time", values_to="val") %>% 
  mutate(time = gsub("X(.*)\\.Elem\\.PPE", "\\1", time), 
         time = gsub("\\.", "/", time))
```

The resulting data frame looks like this:

```
# # A tibble: 40 x 3
#   town    time    val
#   <chr>   <chr> <int>
# 1 Concord 01/02  4965
# 2 Concord 02/03  4953
# 3 Concord 03/04  5066
# 4 Concord 04/05  5100
# 5 Concord 05/06  4979
# 6 Concord 06/07  5090
# 7 Concord 07/08  5136
# 8 Concord 08/09  5076
# 9 Concord 09/10  5079
# 10 Concord 10/11  4945
```

Next, we can make a plot for a single place (before we think about automation).  Let's try Concord.  First, we'll save the values that we want to put on the x-axis:

```
xlabs <- unique(df2$time)
```

Next, we can use `ggplot()` to make the plot.  In the code below, we're first piping the data frame to a filter that will pull out the values for a single town.  The filtered data frame is piped into the `ggplot()` function.  Since `time` in the data frame is a character vector, we need to turn it into a factor and then into a numeric to make the line plot.  We add the line geometry to plot the line.  Then we change the x-axis labels with `scale_x_continuous()`.  The `labs()` function changes the axis labels for the x- and y-axes.  Finally, `ggtitle()` puts the title at the top of the plot.  I also like `theme_bw()` rather than the gray background, but that's entirely a matter of personal preference.  The resulting plot looks like this:

```
df2 %>% filter(town == "Concord") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=as.numeric(as.factor(time)), y=val)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:10, labels = xlabs) + 
  labs(x="Time", y="Spending per Pupil") + 
  ggtitle("Concord") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Now, the next part you mentioned was automation - you want to do this for every row of the original data frame.  We could do that as follows.  First, `untown` grabs the unique values of `town` from the data. The `for()` loop loops from 1 to the number of values in `untown`.  Then you can see where `"Concord"` was in the previous plot, we now have `untown[i]`.  We also use `ggsave()` at the end and we paste together the town name and `.png`.  This will make a different plot for each town in R's working directory.

```
untown <- unique(df2$town)
for(i in 1:length(untown)){
  df2 %>% filter(town == untown[i]) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=as.numeric(as.factor(time)), y=val)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:10, labels = xlabs) + 
    labs(x="Time", y="Spending per Pupil") + 
    ggtitle(untown[i]) + 
    theme_bw()
  ggsave(glue("{untown[i]}.png"), width=9, height=6)
}
```